# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset occurs from server socket

Tags: java, sockets

```
public class NewClass {

ServerSocket myServerSocket;
boolean ServerOn = true;

public NewClass() {
    try {
        myServerSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Could not create server socket on port 8888. Quitting.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }



    while (ServerOn) {
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = myServerSocket.accept();
            ClientServiceThread cliThread = new ClientServiceThread(clientSocket);
            cliThread.start();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception found on accept. Ignoring. Stack Trace :");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        myServerSocket.close();
        System.out.println("Server Stopped");
    } catch (Exception ioe) {
        System.out.println("Error Found stopping server socket");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new NewClass();
}

class ClientServiceThread extends Thread {

    Socket myClientSocket;
    boolean m_bRunThread = true;

    public ClientServiceThread() {
        super();
    }

    ClientServiceThread(Socket s) {
        myClientSocket = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        System.out.println(
                "Accepted Client Address - " + myClientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myClientSocket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(myClientSocket.getOutputStream()));

            while (m_bRunThread) {
                String clientCommand = in.readLine();
                if (clientCommand != null) {
                    System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand);
                }

                if (!ServerOn) {
                    System.out.print("Server has already stopped");
                    out.println("Server has already stopped");
                    out.flush();
                    m_bRunThread = false;
                }
                if (clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                    m_bRunThread = false;
                    System.out.print("Stopping client thread for client : ");
                } else if (clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
                    m_bRunThread = false;
                    System.out.print("Stopping client thread for client : ");
                    ServerOn = false;
                } else {
                    out.println("Server Says : " + clientCommand);
                    out.flush();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                myClientSocket.close();
                System.out.println("...Stopped");
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 8888);


    PrintWriter out =new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    out.print("KKKKKKKKKKKKK \r\n");
    out.flush();
    out.close();



 }
```

The purpose of the above code is to create server socket and client socket to pass data between server and client.When the client sends the data to server .server grab the message and print it on the screen but with following exception.The pop up from the **String clientCommand = in.readLine()**; line which appeared on server code.

```
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting.  The server attempted to continue reading after the client closed its end of the socket, so the server received the appropriate exception.

Comment: @JimGarrison That alone would only cause `readLine()` to return null. There is more to it: the preceding write.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid. Your server code relies on the client implementing the protocol correctly, which this client doesn't. Bad habit. Defensive coding is required. If `clientCommand == null` you must exit this read loop and close the socket. Your present code will attempt to write to the closed connection, which produces exactly this exception ... later.